# How to access a specific cell item in a UICollectionView and Segue to a new View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to segue from a specific cell in my CollectionView in order to access different View Controllers for each cell.

I have successfully found how to segue from a cell item.

```html
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    let selectedIndexPath = interests[indexPath.item]
        
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "FeatureVC", sender: selectedIndexPath)
        
}
```

**Here is an image of my current code**
[image: Code.]

However, figuring out how to segue form a specfic cell is proving more difficult. I have looked at a few answers but nothing seems tp be very straight forward.

I am new to development so I can understand if this question has a simple solution however this will be key for the main functionality of my application so i have to get this right.

Any guidance I can receive would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by seguing from specific cell. Aren't you doing the same thing in the above code?

Comment: I want to be able to segue to a new view controller via just one cell in the CollectionView. The current code triggers the segue from every cell. I apologise if the question is not clear.

Comment: @user8263946 check out the answer below and let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**It seems like you are using the wrong delegate as per your conditions also if you want to segue only one cell you can check the `IndexPath.item`**

change `didDeselectItemAt` to `didSelectItemAtIndexpath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexpath indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if indexPath.item == yourSpecificCellIndex {
      //perform segue
   }
}
```

Comment: what would I replace 'yourDesiredCellindex' with in order to select the cell i want ?

Comment: You have to keep your desired cell index at the class level for comparison at didselectatindexpath..

Comment: This method worked, so thank you for feedback. However, I am finding that it doesn't work straight away after loading the page. I have to scroll through my collectionView before the feature works or sometimes it segues from different cells. Do you have any idea why this might be ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from 1 cell use `didSelectItemAtIndexpath`method.

In that identify your cell using the position at `indexpath.row` and then call the segue accordingly

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    // Use any cell values to identify which one should open segue
}
```

Comment: Where would I enter the cell values in this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

First use `didSelectItem` method. Then write appropriate condition in that:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){


    if condition // your specific condition 
    {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "FeatureVC", sender: selectedIndexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to have your specific item in the featureVC.

So in your FeatureVC class add a variable like

```
var interest : Interest! // this should be the type of what you have in your interests Array
```

In your controller where you perform the segue add a variable on the top like

```
var selectedInterest: Interest!
```

Your function to determine which item you clicked is not correct so use:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedInterest = interests[indexPath.item]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "FeatureVC", sender: nil)

}
```

Now you just need a little bit preparation bevor you segue, so just add:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "FeatureVC" {
        let featureVC = segue.destination as! FeatureVC // your controller name
        featureVC.interest = selectedInterest // here you can set the variable in your feature vc
    }
}
```